# Mediawiki files uploaded, but not displayed (404 error)

Tags: php, mediawiki

I try to insert image on my mediawiki page.
In `php.ini` I set:

```
file_uploads = On
```

In LocalSettings.php I set:

```
$wgEnableUploads = true;
$wgUploadPath = "{$IP}/images";
$wgUsePathInfo = false;
```

Files are uploaded correctly. I see them in `mediawiki/images/a/a2/`, `mediawiki/images/b/be/` or similar locations. I can open these files on server. But...

On the mediawiki images are not displayed and when I click on image link it goes directly to image (`mediawiki/images/a/a2/image.png`) and 404 page is displayed.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to configure your webserver accordingly.  There is a `.htaccess` file in the `images` folder which should do it automatically for Apache, assuming the use of htaccess files is enabled.